# Javascript Object expected error in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am receiving

> "object expected error" with the following code. Error is displayed when the line with "a7.write(a5); " this code is called.

Any suggestions what might be wrong?

```
function _fullChange() {
  if (parent._pprRequestCount > 0) {
    parent._pprRequestCount--;
    if (_agent.isIE) {
      var a0 = _getElementById(document, '_pprDisableWrite');
      a0.text = 'var _pprDocumentWrite = document.write;' +
      'var _pprDocumentWriteln = document.writeln;' +
      'document.write = new Function(\'return;\');' +
      'document.writeln = new Function(\'return;\');';
      var a1 = _getElementById(document, '_pprEnableWrite');
      a1.text = 'document.write = _pprDocumentWrite;' +
      'document.writeln = _pprDocumentWriteln';
    }
    var a2 = document.body;
    var a3 = a2.getAttribute('onload');
    var a4 = a2.getAttribute('onunload');
    a2.setAttribute('onload', _getCommentedScript(document, ('_pprFullOnload')));
    a2.setAttribute('onunload', _getCommentedScript(document, ('_pprFullOnunload')));
    var a5 = _getDocumentContent();
    var a6 = new RegExp('<script id=["]*_pprFullChange.*>_fullChange\\(\\)</script>', 'i');
    a5 = a5.replace(a6, '');
    a2.setAttribute('onload', a3);
    a2.setAttribute('onunload', a4);
    var a7 = parent.document;
    if (_agent.isIE) {
      var a8 = document.charset;
      a7.open();
      a7.charset = a8;
    }    
    // <<<< OBJECT EXPECTED eRROR IS PRODUCED HERE>>
    a7.write(a5);
    a7.close();
  }
}
```

I should add we get the same error when the following lines are commented out

```
 //if (_agent.isIE) {
      var a8 = document.charset;
      a7.open();
      a7.charset = a8;
 //}    
   a7.write(a5);

Object expected error is reported on the last line
```

Comment: not easy to help unless you point out which specific line is causing issue

Comment: if you work with code exactly how you've posted it, no wonder you have a problem - indented code is far easier to read

Comment: pointed out the line with code "**a7.write(a5);**

Comment: please look for text <<<< OBJECT EXPECTED eRROR IS PRODUCED HERE>>.. thanks :)

Comment: I've formatted your code so my eyes wont bleed

Comment: Common12_2_4_0_0.js is the file name, its standard javascript that works in chrome and mozilla, but in IE11 fails with the error

Comment: could it be related to  'text/javascript not being in header?

Comment: what happens if you omit the code in the last `if (_agent.isIE) {`

Comment: same error jaro, we tried with both. the same code works perfectly in chrome.. where if (_agent.isIE) { is commneted out too

Comment: any ideas anyone?